# how to bind dynamic data to an array in angularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax

I am new to angular. I have started a shopping cart web application. So I have found one cart plugin from the web 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576246/A-Shopping-Cart-Application-Built-with-AngularJS. but in this plugin, we can only have static data. I want to have a dynamic data which is fetched from the database. below is my code

default.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="AngularStore">
  <head>
    <title>Shopping Cart with AngularJS</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap, jQuery, Angular-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- AngularStore app -->
    <script src="js/product.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/store.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/shoppingCart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- 
        bootstrap fluid layout
        (12 columns: span 10, offset 1 centers the content and adds a margin on each side)
    -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span10 offset1">
                <h1 class="well" >
                    <a href="default.htm">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" height="60" width="60" alt="logo"/>
                    </a>
                    Angular Store 
                </h1>
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
'use strict';

// App Module: the name AngularStore matches the ng-app attribute in the main <html> tag
// the route provides parses the URL and injects the appropriate partial page
var storeApp = angular.module('AngularStore', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/store', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/store.htm',
        controller: storeController 
      }).
      when('/products/:productSku', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/product.htm',
        controller: storeController
      }).
      when('/cart', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/shoppingCart.htm',
        controller: storeController
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/store'
      });
}]);
```

```
storeApp.factory("DataService", function () {

    // create store
    var myStore = new store();

    // create shopping cart
    var myCart = new shoppingCart("AngularStore");

    // enable PayPal checkout
    // note: the second parameter identifies the merchant; in order to use the 
    // shopping cart with PayPal, you have to create a merchant account with 
    // PayPal. You can do that here:
    // https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/merchant
    myCart.addCheckoutParameters("PayPal", "bernardo.castilho-facilitator@gmail.com");

    // enable Google Wallet checkout
    // note: the second parameter identifies the merchant; in order to use the 
    // shopping cart with Google Wallet, you have to create a merchant account with 
    // Google. You can do that here:
    // https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/training/getting-started/merchant-setup
    myCart.addCheckoutParameters("Google", "500640663394527",
        {
            ship_method_name_1: "UPS Next Day Air",
            ship_method_price_1: "20.00",
            ship_method_currency_1: "USD",
            ship_method_name_2: "UPS Ground",
            ship_method_price_2: "15.00",
            ship_method_currency_2: "USD"
        }
    );

    // return data object with store and cart
    return {
        store: myStore,
        cart: myCart
    };
});
```

store.js

```
function store() {
    this.products = [

       new product("APL", "Apple", "Eat one every…", 12, 90, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2),
       new product("AVC", "Avocado", "Guacamole…", 16, 90, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2),
       new product("BAN", "Banana", "These are…", 4, 120, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2)      

    ];        

}
store.prototype.getProduct = function (sku) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
        if (this.products[i].sku == sku)
            return this.products[i];
    }
    return null;
}
```

In the above code, we are just passing some static data like apple Avocado, instead of that, I want to bind the data which is fetched from the database. I have written PHP code to fetch data but I don't know how we can bind it to the array. that is to the object product.

select.php

```
<?php
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","shopping");

$output=array();

$query="select serial,name,description,price from products";
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
        $output[]=$row;
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To Add Item in your Cart - (You can add data using `addItem(sku, name, price, quantity)` as in the article it is mentioned additem is used to add or remove items from the cart.In the response of your database call use addItem.)

Assuming you have to add Data in the table list so your "select.php" returns the ListOfData then -

```
function yourController($scope,DataService) {

$scope.store = DataService.store;
//Get Call for the list
$scope.getList=function(){
  $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'select.php' }).then(function 
  success(response) 
 { 
    alert(response);
   $scope.posts=response.data; 
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.posts.length;i++){
      $scope.store.products.push(new product($scope.posts[i].sku,  
      $scope.posts[i].name, $scope.posts[i].description, 
      $scope.posts[i].price, $scope.posts[i].cal, 
      $scope.posts[i].carot, 
      $scope.posts[i].fiber, $scope.posts[i].folate, 
      $scope.posts[i].potassium,$scope.posts[i].vitc));
    }
  }, function error(response) { 
     // called asynchronously if an error occurs // 
    or server returns response with an error status. 
  } 
}
$scope.getList();
}
```

As you can see the product class is created as

```
// product class
function product(sku, name, description, price, cal, carot, vitc, folate, potassium, fiber) {
    this.sku = sku; // product code (SKU = stock keeping unit)
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
    this.cal = cal;
    this.nutrients = {
        "Carotenoid": carot,
        "Vitamin C": vitc,
        "Folates": folate,
        "Potassium": potassium,
        "Fiber": fiber
    };
}
```

So we have to push the new data inside products array by creating product class object.

Comment: @Namedo Karande but in this we are passing some static data in the store.js file. But there i want pass these dynamic data. how can i?

Comment: Lets say you have a api call to get CartData inside your store.js file ,so inside that api success functionyou can use addItem.

Comment: $http({
     method: 'GET',
     url: 'select.php'
   }).then(function success(response) {
    alert(response);
       $scope.posts=response.data; 
     }, function error(response) {
       // called asynchronously if an error occurs
       // or server returns response with an error status.
     }

Comment: i want to bind this data to a object called product.

Comment: new product("BAN", "Banana", "These are…", 4, 120, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2) insted of this i want the dynamic data that is response.data to binded. how can i bind this?

Comment: I have edited the answer.Plz accept it as answer if it is helpful to you.